# Updating field of point which fits in region using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a problem when I was working with ArcMap:
I want to get value from a field of a region and update for points which fit in that region,
I don't known what tools can do it.

[image]

What tool should I use?

Comment: Sounds like a Spatial Join would meet your needs. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Here it is expected that you will tell us not just what you want to do but also what you have researched and preferably tried to do before getting stuck and posting.